# How can I output a set of files and directories to JSON using Classic ASP?

Tags: json, asp-classic

Is there way that I can output the file format of the files in the provided tree as JSON so that the following JSON appears as below. I've already tried to set this up using http://www.aspjson.com/ as a reference without any luck. Can someone show me how I need to go about solving this problem to get the provided JSON structure?

## === File Structure: ===

-docs 
--fsum
---2007
----faculty
-----file1.txt
---2008
----faculty2
-----file1.txt
-----file2.txt
----faculty3
-----file1.txt
-----file2.txt

## === Example of JSON: ===

```
[
 {year: '2007', report: 'faculty', files: ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'] },
 {year: '2007', report:'faculty2', files: ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']},
 {year: 2008, report:'faculty3', files: ['file1.text', 'file2.txt'] }
]
```

## === Classic ASP Code ===

```
<%  
dim page, fs, fo, x, c, b, a
page = Server.MapPath("\")
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set fo=fs.GetFolder(page & "\docs\fsum\")


' Gets all of the files inside of the docs folder'

for each x in fo.SubFolders
a = a + 1
newFolder = fo & "\" & x.Name
set fob = fs.Getfolder(newFolder)
for each y in fob.SubFolders
b = b + 1
    newFiles = fo & "\" & x.Name & "\" & y.Name
    set foc = fs.GetFolder(newFiles)
    for each z in foc.files 'get all of the files inside  
        c = c + 1
    next
next
next
For counter = 1 to c
  for each x in fo.SubFolders

next
next

set fo=nothing
set fs=nothing

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to get this to work is to first understand the structure that you want your JSON to be written in. Next, you should output the data from http://www.aspjson.com/ by testing that the object works, and then add in your own values into the provided code to better know where you need to add your for each loops.

Below is an example of how this will work:

```
<!--#include virtual="/aspJSON1.17.asp" -->
<%
response.ContentType = "application/json"
Set oJSON = New aspJSON
With oJSON.data

Dim fs, fo, page, x
d = 0 
page = Server.MapPath("\")
set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set fo = fs.GetFolder(page & "\docs\fsum\")
 'Create value
.Add 0, oJSON.Collection()
With oJSON.data(0)
    for each a in fo.subFolders
        x = x + 1
         .Add x, oJSON.Collection() 
        With .item(x)
            .Add "year", a.Name
           newFolder = fo & "\" & a.Name
           set fob = fs.GetFolder(newFolder)
           for each b in fob.SubFolders
           .Add b.Name, oJSON.Collection()
           With .item(b.Name)
            .Add 1, oJSON.Collection() 
                With .item(1)
                    .Add "files", oJSON.Collection() 
                    With .item("files")
                    newFiles = fo & "\" & a.Name & "\" & b.Name
                    set foc = fs.GetFolder(newFiles)
                    for each z in foc.files 
                    d = d + 1
                        .Add d, z.Name
                    next
                    End With
                End With
             End With
             next
        End With
      next
End With
End With

Response.Write oJSON.JSONoutput() 
%>
```